# drawing a circle in android with openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im looking for a way to draw the OUTLINE of a circle that will basically act as a horizon line.  I don't want to fill the circle, but instead just have a white line that can be seen even when you are looking at it from the side as it lays flat.. is this possible?  can someone show me a tutorial or tell me how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a more efficient way than that posted by SteveL.

Rather than calculate the trig functions for each point (a computationally expensive method), you can find the next point on the circle based on the current point, the tangent vector, and the cosine vector. The trig functions are calculated once, then each subsequent point is a series of multiplications, which are much faster.

This page provides a very clear step-through of the process for OpenGL, but you can easily apply Steve's answer to make it work in OpenGL ES:

http://slabode.exofire.net/circle_draw.shtml

Comment: I love the way he has explained how to draw without using trig functions repeatedly. Although I would love to ask, how he has computed the tx, ty values.

Comment: Also an explanation of drawing arcs so that the direction (CW or CCW) is taken into account would be useful. If you have eg. an offset polygon which we draw round joins using the slabode code, then the starting and ending angles can be in whatever order. Also a polygon can itself be CW or CCW, so the winding order is very significant. The code however works nice, if the arc angle (end angle) is bigger than starting angle.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you use gl.glLineWidth(20);(or another size) the thik of the line will incease too(propably i am wrong but worth trying)

To get the verices of a circle:

```
     float[] verts=MakeCircle2d(1,100,0,0)

     public static float[] MakeCircle2d(float rad,int points,float x,float y)//x,y  ofsets
     {
            float[] verts=new float[points*2+2];
            boolean first=true;
            float fx=0;
            float fy=0;
            int c=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
            {
                    float fi = 2*Trig.PI*i/points;
                    float xa = rad*Trig.sin(fi + Trig.PI)+x ;
                    float ya = rad*Trig.cos(fi + Trig.PI)+y ;
                    if(first)
                    {
                        first=false;
                        fx=xa;
                        fy=ya;
                    }
                    verts[c]=xa;
                    verts[c+1]=ya;
                    c+=2;
            }
            verts[c]=fx;
            verts[c+1]=fy;
            return verts;
      }
```

Draw it as GL10.GL_LINES if you want a empty circle

```
 gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES, 0, verts.length / 2);
```

Or draw it as GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN if you want a filled one

```
 gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, verts.length / 2);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks.. If i wanted now to draw a line down from the empty circle every 5 degrees perpendicular would i do it at the same time or go through the array again?